Access to MXF data
If I try to open a MOV file, I can get the data.
For example like this
let track = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

Next I can extract the metadata or timecode.
But I am completely unable to get the MXF file data.
If I call the same
asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)

Then I get an empty array. I found mention of MTRegisterProfessionalVideoWorkflowFormatReaders, but the function is not documented. Has anyone encountered this?
